# How to identify which file implicitly relies on linkage with a library?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm

I am working on en embedded project. I have integrated open source sub-projects in it (i.e. code I did not write).
Compilation is fine but I have linkage errors:

```
gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o):
In function `abort': abort.c:(.text.abort+0xa): undefined reference to `_exit'
gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o):
In function `_kill_r': signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0x10): undefined reference to `_kill'
gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o):
In function `_getpid_r': signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x0): undefined reference to `_getpid' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also had errors about undefeined reference to `_exit` but I fixed these by searching & replacing calls to `exit(1)`.

I tried to search & replace calls to `abort()` but I still have these errors.

I found some similar questions resolved by adding linker options `-specs=nosys.specs` but this is not what I want.
I want to modify the code so that I can handle errors gracefully without brutally exiting the entire program and to do that I have to find which code relies on this link.

Comment: The documentation of a function should include the header file in which it is defined and the library in which it is implemented/provided.

Comment: I interpret `libc.a` to be (intended to be) a static version of the C standard library.  It is highly suspicious that functions in such a library would have any dependency on anything outside that library, and some of the details look even more suspicious.  I think the library is probably not built properly.

Comment: You shouldn't replace the calls, you should implement the calls itself. If you import a library that uses getpid and kill, then you should implement them on your target system. You sohuld implement `_kill` and `_getpid` and `_exit` functions on your target and decide what they should do. The `gcc-arm-none-eabi` is "bare-metal", there is no OS. And good to note that gcc uses (by default) `newlib` for it's standard library implementation. Why does `nosys.specs` makes your program "brutally exit"?

Comment: The code you imported makes assumptions about environment that do not exists, ex. that you can call getpid on a process. If your bare-metal target doesn't implement posix callbacks, you have to implement them in order to use posix compatible code. The `nosys.specs` just links with a "no system implementation of posix and c calls", ie. most posix calls return -1 and set errno to ENOSYS or similar. The implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/bminor/newlib/tree/master/libgloss/libnosys). Not all calls are masked.

Comment: `I have integrated open source sub-projects` - which projects? `I fixed these by searching & replacing calls to exit(1)` - how did you fix them? For what did you replace them? `-specs=nosys.specs but this is not what I want` why does nosys.specs make you "brutaly exit the entire program"?

Comment: It was a figure of speech. I mean since I don't have process, I don't want the call to terminate my application. I just want the current function to return.
`abort` header is `stdlib.h` which is wildly included in several files.
I cannot implement the `_abort`, `_exit` or `_kill` because I need them to make their caller return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to search & replace calls to abort() but I still have these errors.

I *think* you are asking: "how to find code that calls `abort` (after replacing all calls that you can find)?"

If that is indeed your question, use `-y` linker option. For example:

```
gcc main.o foo.o bar.o -Wl,-y,abort

/usr/bin/ld: bar.o: reference to abort
/usr/bin/ld: //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: definition of abort
```

P.S. Your build of `.../v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libc.a` is highly unusual: generally if it defines `abort` and `exit`, it should *also* define `_exit`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. The call came from the use of `assert`. Now I can either define `NDEBUG` or use my own asser implementation. Thanks